# О породах собак

Tags: значение-слов

Ноздрев в "Мертвых душах" говорит о щенке: "Настоящий мордаш". Где-то я слышал, что он имел в виду конкретную породу. Это правда? Или это слово означает просто мордастого щенка?
Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Я однажды читала, что так в России 19 века называли мастифов. Но не могу сказать, что информация на сто процентов достоверная.

Answer (score 0):

Я тот еще кинолог, но насколько понимаю, это не мастиф, а чисто русская бульдогооподобная линия (не уверен даже, что самостоятельная порода), т.н. **меделянская собака**.  С ними еще при Грозном охотились. 
Сейчас, насколько понимаю, линия это сильно "испортилась" и в чистом виде не существует.
Может поэтому её стали смешивать с мастифом.

(+)

Вопрос о том, имел ли в виду Ноздрев эту породу либо просто отпустил комплимент, для меня остается открытым. Скорее всего именно последнее, поскольку по некоторым источникам, линия выродилась еще в XVIII веке, хотя память о ней сохранилась.